# Trying to implement DRY using jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am trying implement DRY by using jQuery load(). I want to have navbar.html that is on each page and is called by load() rather than having it on each html. All my files are in the same directory at the moment but I cannot seem to make the navbar load on the services page. please see my code below. I think there is a simple solution maybe its my syntax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>A_D Acupuncture in Amsterdam | Best In Amsterdam</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A_D Ac  upuncture is one of the best acupuncturists in Amsterdam. Make an appointment to get the very best service.">
  <meta property="og:title" content="A_D Acupuncture in Amsterdam | Best In Amsterdam">
  <meta property="og:image" content="facebook-card.jpg">
  <meta property="og:description" content="A_D Acupuncture is one of the best acupuncturists in Amsterdam. Make an appointment to get the very best service.">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="A_D Acupuncture"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700|Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js" async=""></script>
```

hello world /* test */

```
<-- Navbar.html -->

  <div class="navbar-ad">
    <div class="navbar-logo">
      <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="../images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-right">
      <a href="index.html" target="_blank" class="navbar-items navbar-home">Home</a>
      <a href="services.html" target="_blank" class="navbar-items navbar-services">Services</a>
      <a href="contact.html" target="_blank" class="navbar-items navbar-contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html");
  $('#h1').html("heeey") /* test line to make sure filepath is correct */
});
```

Comment: With regard to your issue, it's most likely a relative path problem. Try making the path relative to the root of the site, eg. `load('/navbar.html')`. However note that it's a much better idea to include repeated content on the server side than on the client. Doing it this way adds an unnecessary extra request to the server, makes the page load time much slower and results in a FOUC while the `load()` request is in process.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: If this is from harddisk you will get a CORS error - it has to be from a server

Comment: @mplungjan As far as I can tell it works for all other pages except `services.html`.

Comment: Then you have a typo or services.html is in another folder

Comment: thanks @Chris G and mplungjan. Rookie error. I never opened the console and I have a CORS error. I don't know what this is but will investigate and try to fix!

Comment: I see, so @mplungjan was correct. You're getting a CORS error because you're loading the main HTML from `file:///` and XHRs (which jQuery uses to `.load()` stuff) don't work in that realm. I recommend getting XAMPP, and learning about PHP's include; that way you can combine HTML files on the server.